# SurfaceView not animating

Tags: android, animation, android-custom-view

i have created a surfaceView and attached an alpha fade in and fade out animation but it doesnt seem to animate.

Here is my animation code:

```
fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
        fadeOut.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        fadeOut.setDuration(1000);

        fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
        fadeIn.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        fadeIn.setDuration(1000);
animation = new AnimationSet(false); 
        animation.addAnimation(fadeIn);
        animation.addAnimation(fadeOut);

        //this.setAnimation(animation);
        animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
```

inside my onDraw method i simply call this

```
super.onDraw(canvas);
    this.startAnimation(animation);
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions? i tried it on a subclass of View and the animation works

Answer (score 1):

A SurfaceView is a special kind of view. I'm not so familiar with the exact implementation of it, but what I understood is that it creates more or less a hole in your app, and renders the view outside of the normal framework. This causes that it's not possible to do things like animations on it (or at least limits it).

If you really want a fade in animation, I suggest you implement it yourself in your SurfaceView, or you consider extending from View instead of SurfaceView.

Answer (score 1):

Android ICS (v4) added [TextureView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html) which [supports animations](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/android-40-graphics-and-animations.html)

> Because a SurfaceView’s content does not live in the application’s window, it cannot be transformed (moved, scaled, rotated) efficiently. This makes it difficult to use a SurfaceView inside a ListView or a ScrollView. SurfaceView also cannot interact properly with some features of the UI toolkit such as fading edges or View.setAlpha().
>
> To solve these problems, Android 4.0 introduces a new widget called TextureView that relies on the hardware accelerated 2D rendering pipeline and SurfaceTexture. TextureView offers the same capabilities as SurfaceView but, unlike SurfaceView, behaves as a regular view. You can for instance use a TextureView to display an OpenGL scene or a video stream. The TextureView itself can be animated, scrolled, etc.